# What is the shortest non-trivial logical deduction about overlapping circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

For line segments in a 1D infinite space the shortest non-trivial statement I can think of is:

"For line segments $A$, $B$ and $C$. If there are regions where (at least) $A$ and $B$ overlap and regions where $B$ and $C$ overlap and regions where $A$ and $C$ overlap there must be a region where $A$, $B$ and $C$ overlap."

Now in a 2D infinite plane with a number of filled circles $A,B,C,D...$ , you are told some incomplete information about if there are areas where the circles overlap and which circles these are. What it the simplest non-trivial logical deduction that one could make from this information about overlaps in the same sort of way as was done with line segments?

Comment: If you really just want the "simplest" deduction then this is surely opinion-based.

Comment: Well OK, by simplest I mean fewest circles and shortest statement.

Comment: Same as the line segments.  If A and B intersect, B and C intersect, C and A intersect, then there is a region (possibly a point) where all 3 intersect

Comment: @NazimJ Not true! You could have a hole in the middle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If three or more (but only finitely-many) circular regions in the plane are such that any three have a point in common, then all of them have a point in common.*

(The case of three regions is, of course, tautological, but including it makes for the most-complete statement of the result.) This, and OP's segment example, are special cases of [Helly's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem), which can be expressed as:

> *If $d+1$ or more (but only finitely-many) convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ are such that any $d+1$ of them have a point in common, then all of them have a point in common.*

(Again, the case of $d+1$ subsets is tautological.) As the Wikipedia article notes, the version of the theorem for infinitely-many regions requires the regions to be *compact* as well as convex.

---

It's worth noting that the *topology* of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is important here. If OP's example were not about *segments* on the *line* but *arcs* on a *circle*, pairwise intersections *do not* imply a common intersection. Nor does the statement I mentioned if "circular regions in the plane" is replaced by "*caps* on the sphere".

Comment: Thanks. That answers the question.

Comment: BTW Is there a version of Helly's theoream where the N-spheres are on a the surface of an (N+1)-sphere?

Comment: A web search for "Helly theorem on sphere" turns up a number of references to "Helly-type" results.